# GWT ComboBox element data is cuts off when width of combo box is small

Tags: css, gwt, combobox, width, hidden

I am using GWT Combo Box widget. I faced an issue of hiding text of combox box if its width is smaller than the text length.

[image: Combox Image]

As this image shows, last element text is hide due to smaller width of combo box. So I want to show full text even in multiple line. How can I achieve this task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is in the `x-combo-list-item` css class of standard `GWT-ext` `ext-all.css` file; there is a `white-space: nowrap` line here. To make items inside the combobox multiline, you've to override this style, setting `white-space: normal`. The first way to do it that came into my head is to use this example: http://gwt-ext.com/demo/#styledComboBox. Here you can see an HTML template that you can use to build item of combobox. For example, you can use this template, if it suites your needs:

```
<div class=\"x-combo-list-item\" style=\"white-space: normal\">" + "{name}</div>"
```